# Save files in database with entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, upload

I have an ASP.NET MVC solution built on Entity Framework with Microsoft SQL Server 2008. I need to create a function that lets my users upload files.

What I would like is:

- A solution that uses the Entity Framework to store files in the Database
- A solution that detects and prevents from uploading the same file twice via some kind of hash/checksum
- Tips on database/table design

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "right" way to store a file in a SQL Server 2008 database is to [use the FILESTREAM data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/filestream-data). I'm not aware that the Entity Framework supports that, but you can certainly try and see what happens.

That said, most of the time when people do this, they don't store the file in the database. Doing so means that you need to go through ASP.NET and the database server just to serve a file which you could be serving directly from the web server. It can also somewhat complicate the backup picture for your database and site. So when we upload files to our MVC/Entity Framework, we store only a reference to the file location in the database, and store the file itself elsewhere.

Obviously, which strategy is right for you depends a lot on the particulars of your application.

Comment: The link is not valid anymore.

Answer (score 46):

In your entity model, map the BLOB database column to a `byte[]` property. Assign the content of the uploaded file to that property of the entity object, and save changes in the `ObjectContext`.

To compute a hash, you can use the [`MD5CryptoServiceProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5cryptoserviceprovider.aspx) class

Comment: What's wrong with that answer ? Could you at least give a reason for the downvote ? That's the one thing I really hate on SO : people who downvote without an explanation... it's so useless

Comment: Got no idea... but take a +1 for your trouble. :)

Comment: The bad part about this is that large files could blow up your RAM by using byte arrays instead of streams :(

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I do it for Podcasts:

```
ID     Title         Path                    Summary              UploadDate
---    -----        --------              ----------------        -----------
1     TestPodcast   /Podcasts/ep1.mp3      A test podcast         2010-02-12
```

The `path` stores a reference to the physical location of the Podcast. I used a post from Scott Hanselman on [File Uploads with ASP.NET MVC](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABackToBasicsCaseStudyImplementingHTTPFileUploadWithASPNETMVCIncludingTestsAndMocks.aspx) to deal with the file upload part.

Comment: This might be ok for a small application, but assuming a complex app with backup requirements and files change over time you wouldn't be able to get back to a specific point in time

Comment: @Ozz You're absolutely right; but this isn't meant for files that change over time. My hope is that once you release a podcast, you're not going to go back and just overwrite that podcast.

Answer (score 0):

A working example (only for file upload because this one comes first in google) on basis of @Thomas's answer :

```
public void AddDocument(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            try
            {                
                    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            using (var ctx = new Entities())
                            {

                            EntityDoc doc = new EntityDoc(); //The document table 

                            doc.DocumentFileName = file.FileName; //The file Name

                            using (var reader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(file.InputStream))
                            {
                                doc.DocumentFile = reader.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength); // the Byte [] Field
                            }
                            ctx.EntityDocs.Add(doc);


                                ctx.SaveChanges();
                                scope.Complete();
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {                          
                            throw ex;
                        }
                    }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was thought that best way of storing files with database it is storing only string path of this files in server (in other words, storing files in folders while, in database storing only their string path). Something like this I use (there also random naming system in order to avoid same naming problem among many users while keeping all data in same folder):

```
public static class FileExtensions
{
    public static string RootPath { get; set; }

    public static bool IsValidSize(this IFormFile file, float kb = 20)
        => file.Length <= kb * 1024;

    public static bool IsCorrectType(this IFormFile file, string contentType = "image")
        => file.ContentType.Contains(contentType);

    public static async Task<string> SaveAsync(this IFormFile file, string path = "data")
    {
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
        string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName).Length > 32 ?
            file.FileName.Substring(0, 32) :
            Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName);
        fileName = Path.Combine(path, Path.GetRandomFileName() + fileName + extension);
        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(Path.Combine(RootPath, fileName)))
        {
            await file.CopyToAsync(fs);
        }
        return fileName;
    }
}
```