# how to save and retrieve file in database as blob in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I need to save a file in database as binary and a method that retrieves the binary file that is stored as blob in the database .. can anyone write the code and tell me the way that I can save the file in the database as blob ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not knowing which RDBMS you're using and if you're coding in C# or VB.Net I can only point you in a general direction. Here are a couple of links:

- [**Working with binary large objects (BLOBs)**](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/Ashush/working-with-binary-large-objects-blobs/) (C# using ADO.NET)
- [**Writing BLOB Values to a Database**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4f5s1we0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (VB.Net using ADO.NET)
- [**Save files in database with entity framework**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288163/save-files-in-database-with-entity-framework) (C# with Entity Framework)