# Download Blob as a file in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am saving a file to MySQL database as blob. Could you please help me, how can I download this blob as a file? I have blob data and `ContentType` in the database. You can see my method for downloading below. I have been searching for over a week, but I couldn't make it. I also don't know that I can download directly over method or I need to write ajax. I highly appreciate your help and assistance. Thanks a lot!

**Method:**

```
public HttpPostedFileBase Indir()
{
    using (ISession session=FluentNHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
    {
        var doc = new Document();
        var docDet = new DocumentDetail();

        doc = session.Query<Document>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 5);
        docDet = session.Query<DocumentDetail>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.DocumentId == doc.Id);

        var test = new MemoryPostedFile(docDet.File, doc.DocumentName, doc.DocumentExtention);
        return test;
    }
}
```

**Class:**

```
public class MemoryPostedFile:HttpPostedFileBase
{
    private readonly byte[] fileBytes;

    public MemoryPostedFile(byte[] fileBytes, string fileName = null, string ContentType = null)
    {
        this.fileBytes = fileBytes;
        this.FileName = fileName;
        this.ContentType = ContentType;
        this.InputStream = new MemoryStream(fileBytes);
    }

    public override int ContentLength => fileBytes.Length;

    public override string FileName { get; }
    public override string ContentType { get; }
    public override Stream InputStream { get; }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to save and retrieve file in database as blob in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439949/how-to-save-and-retrieve-file-in-database-as-blob-in-asp-net).  See also: [MySQL 5.5.9.3 Reading a BLOB from the Database to a File on Disk](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connectors/en/connector-net-programming-blob-reading.html)

Comment: The proper way is to make a HTTP Handler. The classes with "Posted" in the name are for files uploaded from the user. You want to give the user soemthing to download. IHTTPHanlder is propably the droid you are looking for.

Comment: Just to note, since you mentioned it in the question, you can't download files via AJAX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much for your answers! I found the solution and I am writing the code block below.

```
public HttpPostedFileBase Indir(string documentId)
    {
       using (ISession session=FluentNHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
        {

            var doc = new Document();
            var docDet = new DocumentDetail();

            doc = session.Query<Document>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == Convert.ToInt32(documentId));
            docDet = session.Query<DocumentDetail>().FirstOrDefault(x=>x.DocumentId==doc.Id);
            var test = new MemoryPostedFile(docDet.File,doc.DocumentName,doc.DocumentExtention);
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = doc.DocumentExtention;//"application/octet-stream";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename="+test.FileName+";");
            Response.BinaryWrite(docDet.File);
            Server.MapPath("~/"+test.FileName);
            Response.End();
            return test;
        }
    }
```